# I update the user table of the mysql and then mysql access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, access-denied

I update the user table of the mysql database and then I can not connect the database.when I connect the database which says:

```
access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I update the host column of the user table,and then I can not login to the database.
I can login the database before I update the user table, then I stop and then setup mysql service, I can not login.

Who can help me,any help will be appreciated.

Comment: run >FLUSH PRIVILEGES; to reload the table or restart the database, this will also read it

Comment: I already restarted the service.

Comment: what do you have changed in the user table ?

Comment: I can not remeber clearly. I may be change the host from 'localhost' to '::1''.

Comment: @BerndBuffen thank you help me.I have solved the problem. I had mistakenly change the host from '127.0.0.1' to '::' and then I restarted mysql service.I can not connect the mysql anymore. I changed the my.ini file and add 'skip-grant-tables' then I can connect then I change the user table and everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I had mistakenly change the host from '127.0.0.1' to '::' and then I restarted mysql service.I can not connect the mysql anymore. I changed the my.ini file and add 'skip-grant-tables' then I can connect then I change the user table and everything is OK.